# Flash Messages Not Displayed on Redirect to reset_password Page

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on an Express.js application and I'm facing an issue with flash messages not being displayed when I redirect to the reset_password page after submitting the password. Here's what I've tried:

```
I'm using the express-flash middleware to manage flash messages.
I'm setting the flash messages using req.flash() and can see them in the terminal using console.log() just before the redirect.
My view templates have the correct code to display the flash messages, and I've verified the template rendering logic.
```

However, when I'm redirected to the reset_password page, the flash messages don't appear on the page. I'm unable to figure out what might be causing this issue.

```
module.exports.getEmail = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let errors = [];
        const email = req.body.email;
        if (req.user.email === email) {
            const user = await User.findOne({ email: email }); // find user in the database
            if (user) {
                req.flash('success_msg', 'Change Your Password');
                console.log('Flash message set:', req.flash('success_msg'));
                return res.render('reset_password', {
                    title: 'Reset Password'
                });
                

            }

        } else {
            // res.redirect('back')
            errors.push({ msg: 'Enter your email again' });
            if (errors.length > 0) {
                res.render('reset', {
                    errors,
                    email,
                    title: 'reset'
                });
            }
            console.log('user is not same');
        }

    } catch (err) {
        
        errors.push({ msg: 'Wrong Email Enter your email again' });
    }
}

//ejs

<% if (success_msg != '') { %>
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <%= success_msg %>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

I've also verified that the middleware order is correct, and the view rendering logic seems fine.

Any suggestions on what might be causing the flash messages to not appear after the redirect?

Thanks in advance for any help!